# How to choose the right model after k-fold cross validation is done?

Tags: cross-validation, naive-bayes

I'm using naive bayes to classify tweet into three classes. and i want to use k-fold cross validation to predict the right model, but i'm confused how to choose the right model after k-fold validation is done.

Answer (score 1):

If the miss classification rate of one of the methods dominates all the others go with it.

Otherwise pick a norm, look at total miss-classification rate, or weight the miss-classification rates based on some need.  You just need to reduce the space of results to a scalar in a way that seems reasonable for your problem.